# SQL- pick up Max value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max

My question is about How to pick up the Max Value from Crude_Rate

[image]

There are many same State and Year, As a part of the picture.

This is my code

```
SELECT M.Year, M.State, M.Disease, MAX(M.Crude_Rate) 
FROM `MultipleDiseases` M
WHERE M.Year = 2000
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT S.Disease From MultipleDiseases S WHERE S.Disease = "Total" AND S.Disease = M.Disease) 
GROUP BY M.State
```

I want to find the max value of crude_rate and it is related to Disease columns.
For example,

there is my outcome from the above coding

[image]

However, Disease column and Crude_Rate column can not match correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: share text sample input and output not image for getting help faster

Comment: Your sample data is not matching with your outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated sub-query :

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM `MultipleDiseases` M
WHERE M.Year = 2000
      M.Crude_Rate = (SELECT MAX(M1.Crude_Rate) 
                      FROM `MultipleDiseases` M1 
                      WHERE M1.State = M.State AND M1.Disease <> "Total"
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select md.*,
from (select md.*,
             row_number() over (partition by state order by crude_rate desc) as seqnum
      from multiplediseases md
     ) md
where seqnum = 1;
```